# Проверка почтового адреса регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Проблема в работе последнего куска регулярного выражения `.[a-z]{2,3}?` — количество букв не регулируется, работает только в меньшую степень, если меньше двух будет ошибка, а больше — можно печатать сколько душе угодно. Подскажите, где я ошибся.

```
if (preg_match('#^[A-Za-z0-9._-]{4,}@[a-z]{3,}.[a-z]{2,3}?#', $_POST['email']) == 1) {
    $mail=1;
} else {
    $mailpass ='Check your email';
}
```

Comment: Без ограничения на конец строки ($) проверка просто заканчивается на этих символах и остальные не смотрит. Но такая проверка в принципе не корректа, так как в наше время есть огромное количество доменов у которых корневой домен более 3 символов, и в них то же может быть почта. Вот полный перечень https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, лучше `\.` вместо просто точки. А просто точка это любой символ, так что сработает даже на `asasdasd@asdsada`

Во-вторых, почему `[a-z]` и почему `{3,}` ? Разве домен не может быть 33.com, то есть в виде цифр и в два символа?

Ну и в конце есть знак вопроса, что означает ленивый, и в то же время нет конца строки `$` - вот и выходит, что подойдёт даже asdf@ghj.ssssssssssssssssssss, потому что без конца строки шаблон `{2,3}?` совпадёт с `ss`. А остальное просто не запрещено как бы. Так что нужно указать, что это конец строки.

В общем, странные у вас требования к e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите указать точку как точку ее надо экранировать `\.`.

Знак вопроса лишний в конце.

Я заменил расширение `{1,0}` от 1 и больше символа можно оставить `{2,3}`.

> ^[A-Za-z0-9._-]{4,}@[a-z]{3,}.[a-z]{1,}

Кстати первая часть `{4,}` - обязательна ли от 4 символов должно быть?